# Removing an item from an order ArrayList

Tags: java, oop, arraylist

Hello all I'm new to Java and still trying to get my head around on arrays, any help is very appreciated. My program needs  to read a CSV file such as below and either delete or add one person to the ArrayList

```
person, add, personid, firstname
person, del, personid
```

So I am trying to figure out how to best go about this, I basically need to search an ordered array list and delete that one person from the list.

code from main class.

```
public static void processPersonDeletion(String[]theLines){
    Person personDel = new Person();
    setPersonAttributes(personDel, theLines);

    if(!personDel.equals(theLines)){
        System.out.println("Person with license " + theLines[2] + " has "
                + "been removed from the log \nAll persons "
                + "properties will will also be removed from their "
                + "property log");

    }
}
```

code from second class

```
public class PersonLogImpl {

    private boolean remove;
    private boolean isPersonIdUnique;
    private boolean add;
    private ArrayList<Person> person = new ArrayList<>();


    public ArrayList<Person> getPersonLog(){
        return person;
    }

    public boolean add(person obj){  //add person object to ordered list 
       person.add(obj);

   return add;
   }

   public boolean remove (String license){ //remove Person with specific license from list
        person.remove(license);                                    // and return true if successful
       return remove;
   }

   // test if person with specific personid exists in log
    public boolean isPersonIdUnique(String license){

        isLicenseUnique = true;

        return isLicenseUnique;
   }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

In an `arrayList` you can find the index of an element with

```
int index = MyArrayList.indexof(MyObject)
```

And then you can remove it using

```
MyArrayList.remove(index)
```

---

Anyway, I think you should do

```
ArrayList<Person> person = new ArrayList<Person>();
```

in the constructor.

Comment: why find the index when you can use `remove(Object o)`

Comment: That is what I was wondering, I have to pass in the value as a string, so in the second class I need my remove method to search the ArrayList for my passed in string and remove it if found. I think I'm missing a good deal of code to do this however....